# How to get duplicate id via python api?

Tags: python

I try to copy my model and append it as child.

[image]
Before

[image]
After

When I try to duplicate by `bpy.ops.object.duplicate()`.

It will return `{'FINISHED'}` which is not useful for accessing it!

I can't put any operation when the item id is unknown!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the object for further operations it's best to do the duplication without the operator.

```
data_copy = bpy.data.objects["Cube"].data.copy()
obj_copy = bpy.data.objects["Cube"].copy()
obj_copy.data = data_copy
bpy.data.collections["Collection"].objects.link(obj_copy)
obj_copy.parent = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to do it without the operator like in the answer by rjg, however after the operator is run the duplicated object becomes the active object, so it's `bpy.context.object` and if you are duplicating a few objects, all the duplicates become selected so they are all in `bpy.context.selected_objects` .